# GCP - Cloud Functions using python stdout

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

Using cloud functions I found that I can´t get `print()` output.

Example function:

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        print('test print!')
        return f'Hello World!'
```

Using the TEST tool from GCP y get `Hello World!` result, but I can't see `test print!` output.

Where/How can I found it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Log messages are sent to [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging). There are several methods to view/read those logs.

This [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) takes you to the Google Cloud Console Logs Viewer. You can then select "Cloud Functions" to see log entries.

You can also see the logs for a function in the Google Cloud Console -> Compute -> Cloud Functions. Select the "LOGS" tab.

[Writing, Viewing, and Responding to Logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging)

Verify that your function has an IAM Role granting rights to write to Cloud Logging.

[Logging Access Control Guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control)

Comment: Hi, thakns for your answer. This show me logs about execution. I´m looking for the execution output: `print(...)`. I made a mistake. I've edited my question.

Comment: I used Azure function but I think it's similar to GCP, import logging package as `import logging` and to print what you want do `logging.info('test print!')`, hope it helps :)

Comment: @Gocht - Read the last link. This shows you how to write output to Cloud Logging. When you use a `print` statement that sends the output to `stdout`. `stdout` goes to Cloud Logging.

Comment: @Gocht Your question update/edit states you cannot find it. Where are you looking?

Comment: @JohnHanley 'Register Explorer' in Cloud Logging. There I can find execution logs, but I can't find my prints.

Comment: @Gocht What is "Register Explorer"? Show a screenshot in your question. If the logs are not appearing, make sure that the service account assigned to your Cloud Functions function has a Cloud logging role that permits logging. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control

Comment: @JohnHanley This is a link to an screenshot https://ibb.co/j4BQSJ6

Comment: @Gocht I cannot tell anything from the screenshot. It appears that you have created a search pattern and I can only see the right-hand side of the pattern. Just display "Cloud Functions" -> "All logs". Do not expand a log entry so that I can see what is logged. If necessary temporarily switch the "Legacy Viewer" which has fewer options to set correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley Just filtered to show Cloud Functions https://ibb.co/p2yBJ3Q

Comment: @Gocht - Please provide a screenshot using the Legacy Viewer with no search options and no log entries expanded. Also, check if you have a "global" entry that is the default for some log entry types.

Comment: @JohnHanley https://ibb.co/vqtHykm No global entry.

Comment: @Gocht - All I see are "audit logs" which means you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @JohnHanley that's a start. Where should I? I can't see any filter or option to find the execution output.

Comment: @Gocht - You are "filtering" the entries in Logs Viewer. In the top left of the window select the top icon. In English this is "Operations Logging" and not one of its children. Then select "Cloud Functions" and "All logs". If you do not see those items to select you are in the wrong place.

Comment: @JohnHanley This is it https://ibb.co/FngBpVX . Child 'legacy log viewer' is selected by default. This is what I see

Comment: cloud functions, all registers

Comment: @Gocht - Which IAM roles are assigned to the service account that your Cloud Function function is using?

Comment: @Gocht - Review the link that I sent you on how to do logging. Use the Python library and create a test log event. Then see if that appears in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley If i use logging library, where should I see that logs?

Comment: @Gocht - In the same place where I have asked you to look. What do you see here? `You can also see the logs for a function in the Google Cloud Console -> Compute -> Cloud Functions. Select the "LOGS" tab.`

Comment: @JohnHanley https://ibb.co/pjkmnzd This is what I see in Cloud Functions screen, I don't see a "LOGS" tab. Can you point it to me?

Comment: @Gocht - you need to select (click) a function name. Then you can view the logs for that function.

Comment: @JohnHanley If you mean this https://ibb.co/7Wwp1Gb . No prints or any output there. Am I missing a permission?

Comment: @Gocht - Did you double-check that the service account granting your function has rights to log to Cloud Logging? https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control

Comment: @JohnHanley I think problem is close. Whats of this rights should I get?

Comment: @Gocht - Add the Logs Writer Role `roles/logging.logWriter`. That role provides your function with the ability to write to Cloud Logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have to ask permissions. I will try when I get it. Thanks a lot for your support !!!

Answer (score 0):

You find your print statement in the Logs tab of Cloud Functions:

[image: logging inside Cloud Functions]

OR you can find it in Cloud Logging.
To find your message quickly, it helps to filter on: `resource.type="cloud_function"`

[image: cloud functions print statement in Cloud Logging]

If you are using 2nd generation Cloud Functions then filter in Cloud Logging on:
`resource.type="cloud_run_revision"`